# Pubnub Addon on Heroku

Tags: heroku, pubnub

As per the below link, heroku does provide us the addon for pubnub.
https://addons.heroku.com/pubnub

However, there is no information on support of number of connections in each pacakage.

Can someone provide me the information on this?
or
Are Number of connections unlimited for heroku?

Thanks,
Abdul

Answer (score 0):

When you add PubNub to your Heroku account you start with a Sandbox tier account which allows you to have up to 100 connections and send up to 1 million messages per month.  You can see more about the PubNub pricing tiers here: http://www.pubnub.com/pricing.  I hope this helps!

Wendy (from PubNub)

Comment: The following link from Heroku, says that it allows only 150,000/mo Messages for starting package. This confuses me, as pricing on Pubnub is different and pubnub on heroku is different.

Comment: Heroku has its own pricing and PubNub has its own pricing. Just go open an account directly through PubNub and just follow the example/tutorials/docs to you app running. Contact support@pubnub.com if you require further assistance. Cheers.